# Asp.net mvc. logout по апи

Tags: asp.net, c#, mvc

`asp.net mvc 4`.
На сайте используется авторизация с помощью форм.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

Все четко работает. Возникла задача сделать логаут через апи: т.е. пользователь работает на другом сайте (далее - пхп), жмет там логаут, пхп шлет мне на сайт запрос, я его обрабатываю:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
```

Респонз идет на пхп сервер и собственно все. У пользователя в браузере авторизационные куки как были, так и остались, т.е. мой респонз доходит только до хпх сайта, а пользователю ответ шлет пхп сайт.

Ребята, кто сталкивался, как можно решить? Как я понял, нужно неким образом сделать авторизационные куки пользователя недействительными?

Answer (score 2):

Если авторизация через Forms, то в контроллере сделайте такой вот Action:

```
public ActionResult LogOff() 
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
}
```

Или тоже самое, но вручную:

```
public ActionResult LogOff() 
{
    var authCookies = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(session.UserId.ToString(), false);
    authCookies.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но это немного не то. Никакие редиректы работать не будут, т.к. с моим сайтом работает другой пхп-сайт (не пользователь). Разницы нет, какой ответ я ему пошлю, хоть редирект, хоть 404, хоть 500. Пользователь как был на странице пхп-сайта, так он на ней и останется. То же самое и с куки. Никакая кука до пользователя не дойдет, пользователь работает с пхп сайтом.
Т.е. мой сайт используется в данном случае, как вэб сервис.

Comment: @Patient в таком случае, вам надо изучать API того сайта, с которым вы работаете и посылать ему запрос на логаут.